# AWS CodeBuild fails to interact with RDS instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-codebuild

I have the most basic setup in AWS:

- a publicly accessible RDS instance (PostgreSQL 9.6.6 - same as my development one)
- a CodeBuild project

both in the default VPC.

My application is written in Laravel 5.5 and the `buildspec.yml` runs `./artisan migrate --force` at some point and CodeBuild outputs the following error:

```
[Container] 2018/03/10 19:41:36 Running command php artisan migrate --force

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] 
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from information_schema. 
tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)     

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] 
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired    

[PDOException] 
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired
```

Where should I start looking for an error?

Comment: What is your RDS security group looks like? is it open to code build? you can find the IP ranges here for code build https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I just used the default security group created by RDS. The inbound rule is `86.127.247.14/32` and outbound rule is `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: So, it means only 86.127.247.14 can access your DB, go here https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json, search for CODEBUILD and choose your region, add that IP to the inbound rule and then give it a try?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it? I will edit your answer to add some information so people can be aware of these things

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make sure that the RDS security group allows inbound traffic from Code Build.

1. Go to https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
2. Search for `CODEBUILD` and choose your region.
3. Add the IP to the inbound rule in the RDS Security Groups.

Comment: I've seen this advice in a couple places. Isn't this somewhat of a security issue? Wouldn't this mean anyone using CodeBuild in that region can potentially access your DB (although they would still need credentials)?

Comment: Good question, but not exactly. The request from someone else's CodeBuild environment would also need to be able to route requests to your RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Security Group for Code Build and reference it as a source from the DBSecurity Group.

Comment: That's true, but this only helps if you already had known the details beforehand, and i.e. forgot or lost track, and just needed a quick reminder. But for readers who have no idea what's happening - it tell them nothing. So, dear reader, be sure to see [answer from "Mar 10, 2018 at 20:50" by "Sudharsan Sivasankaran's"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213904/717732)