# AWS Codebuild Project Unable to communicate with RDS db

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, aws-codebuild

I am attempting to have AWS CodeBuild run a Flyway migration. The DB and CodeBuild Project are created via Terraform (the pipeline runs as a GitHub action, if it matters)

That code is [here](https://gist.github.com/afisher-stelligent/e91f4e12e123377365e5a26abcf1a9b1).

I figured this solution would make the difference: [AWS CodeBuild fails to interact with RDS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213424/aws-codebuild-fails-to-interact-with-rds-instance)

When the CodeBuild project is executed by my GitHub workflow (using the `aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build` action), the migration times out:

```
[Container] 2022/10/07 21:03:56 Running command flyway -user=$DB_USER -password=$DB_PASSWORD -url=jdbc:mariadb://$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DB_NAME -createSchemas=true migrate
ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mariadb://***:***/***) for user '***': Could not connect to address=(host=***)(port=***)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:***, port:***. connect timed out
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08000
Error Code : -1
Message    : Could not connect to address=(host=***)(port=***)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:***, port:***. connect timed out

Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=***)(port=***)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:***, port:***. connect timed out
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:***, port:***. connect timed out
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

This tells me it's some sort of networking problem but I can't put my finger on what route might be missing. No NACLs other than the defaults. Just security groups. I have a similar pipeline in the AWS CDK that works. As near as I can tell, the security groups and IAM permissions are identical, as is the database config itself.

Looking for debugging tips or anything that's missing.

Comment: Are you sure the IAM role assigned to CodeBuild has the necessary permissions?

Comment: Pretty sure... just compared to an app that's working, and I actually give MORE permissions in the above code than are necessary. I still think I'm missing a network route since flyway's barking on a socket error.

Just for fun, I gave the role FULL access to RDS and still no go.

Comment: This seems like routing/SG issues.  Is the codebuild job configured to be in the same VPC as your database?  If not, is your database public and does it have security groups that allow internet access?  You should provide the networking info of your codebuild job and also the database (SG rules, routes, etc).

Comment: @JDD yes. I’ve told the codebuild project to be in the same VPC… thought those were in the Gist, but maybe not

Comment: I did include all the networking information for the codebuild project, it's here: https://gist.github.com/afisher-stelligent/e91f4e12e123377365e5a26abcf1a9b1#file-main-tf-L519 and all the SG and subnet information is in there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting the `vpc_security_group_ids` parameter on your `aws_db_instance` resource. In that collection should be the security group you associated with your codebuild project. Currently it doesn't appear that your database has an associated security group and so traffic coming from your codebuild project isn't whitelisted and cannot make it through.

See [Terrform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#vpc_security_group_ids)

Comment: Boom! That was what I was missing! Thanks @jstewart379!